# How to Publish a status with multiple photos by Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with Facebook Graph API. Is there any way to "attach multiple photos within a status post" using the Graph API (Javascript SDK)?

With the iOS Facebook app can post a status with multiple photos.

However, after looking through the documentation on internet I couldn't find out how it works.
Does anyone have idea? [This a status screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ncN.png) that I would like to generate with the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

1. Create a post with just a message, get its ID
2. Upload all your photos with `{ "published" : "false" }`, get their
   IDs
3. Update each photo with `{ "target_post" : "<yourPostID>",
   "published" : "true" }`

Answer (score -2):

Did you see this documentation ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/ 
it might help you

Comment: i've read this document, but this document is talking about define new action type. Does Facebook app in iOS use the same way to publish photos?

Comment: @GrassboyWu: How did you achieve it? Could you share the solution?