# Publishing a single facebook post with multiple photos

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to publish a single post with multiple photos? e.g. - [sample facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/MarmzCaterers/posts/745118592187605)

You can do this on the Facebook Page when composing a post ([composing a post with many photos](http://www.m3group.biz/blog/attaching-multiple-images-to-a-facebook-post)).

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348124/how-to-publish-a-status-with-multiple-photos-by-facebook-api) but I don't want to create a story.

I want to create a POST on the PAGE with a collection of photos that I can track likes and comments on like the example stated earlier.

I am using the Facebook SDK.Net that has a batch upload feature - but that creates a post per photo.

Is there a way it be done? Or are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that it is possible to do a Post with multiple photos using the Graph API.  Creating a Facebook Post means sending a POST to the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed`.  In that endpoint, you can include a "picture" property in the query string.  This is the URL of the picture you want to include in the Facebook post.  In your created post Facebook does not reference your picture from that URL, it makes a copy.
Example POST request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?message=check%20out%20this%20picture&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mydomain.com%2Fmyphoto.png
```

On the desktop and mobile apps, you can add as many photos as you like but they are still uploaded individually. Using the console you can see that they are uploaded using the endpoint https://upload.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/media/saveunpublished  It is only after you press the "Post" button are they then associated with your status message.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was looking for way to associate or link a photo uploaded to a post on the timeline. I wonder if that is possible?